# Bootable SD Card Doesn't Show Up in BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu, bios, sd-card

I installed **Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** on my HDD drive and now want to install it on an SSD drive instead. My laptop is Samsung 300E4A (BIOS version 09QA).

I used **Startup Disk Creator** to write `lubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso` to my 64 GB SD card. When I reboot my laptop, however, the bootable SD card doesn't show up in BIOS.

Some screenshots:

[image: SD card (1)]

[image: HDD drive (2)]

[image: Boot Priority Order (3)]

**BIOS -> Advanced**: `Legacy USB Support [Enabled]` and `UEFI Boot Support [Disabled]`.

The **grub** file in `/etc/default`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=217d971f-1e80-4264-9db9-048d766f08e5"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a new EFI-bootable disk (SD card), and your BIOS is configured to use legacy (MBR) boot. That doesn't work.

You have to decide if you want your machine to use EFI boot from now on (and keep using that SD card), but that will affect all other systems that you have on your other disks; they won't boot anymore, or you'll have to reinstall them. If that's what you want, change your BIOS from "Legacy Boot" to "UEFI boot".

If you want to keep other systems on that machine (Windows?), better create a new boot disk / SD card that uses legacy boot, too.

Also, check if your BIOS can even boot from SD cards at all. The SD card reader may show up as a USB device in the BIOS.

HTH